# gdal_translate error 1: output driver not found

Tags: error, gdalwarp

I'm using gdalwarp from gisinternals msvc compiled binaries.

There should be a script which specifies the path variables. It was given inside the binaries. I modified in a small way such that it works from outside the directory and some other paths are also specified.

```
@echo off

set SDK_ROOT=%~dp0gdal\
set SDK_ROOT=%SDK_ROOT:\\=\%
set GNUPLOT_ROOT=%~dp0gnuplot\
set GSL_ROOT=%~dp0gsl2\

goto setenv
set PYTHON_ROOT=%~dp0python1\


@echo %SDK_ROOT%
@echo %GNUPLOT_ROOT%


if "%1" == "setenv" goto setenv

%comspec% /k "%SDK_ROOT%SDKShell.bat" setenv %1
goto exit

:setenv
@echo Setting environment for using the GDAL and MapServer tools.

if "%2"=="hideoci" goto hideoci

set ocipath=0
set _path="%PATH:;=" "%"
for %%p in (%_path%) do if not "%%~p"=="" if exist %%~p\oci.dll set ocipath=1

if "%ocipath%"=="0" goto hideoci
@echo WARNING: If you encounter problems with missing oci libraries then type:
@echo   SDKShell hideoci
goto setenv2

:hideoci
@echo Hiding the OCI plugin library.
if not exist "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins-optional" mkdir "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins-optional"
if exist "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins\ogr_OCI.dll" move "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins\ogr_OCI.dll" "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins-optional\ogr_OCI.dll"
if exist "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins\gdal_GEOR.dll" move "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins\gdal_GEOR.dll" "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins-optional\gdal_GEOR.dll"


:setenv2
@echo At set env 2
SET "PATH=%SDK_ROOT%bin;%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\python\osgeo;%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\python\;%SDK_ROOT%bin\proj6\apps;%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\apps;%SDK_ROOT%bin\ms\apps;%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\csharp;%SDK_ROOT%bin\ms\csharp;%SDK_ROOT%bin\curl;%GNUPLOT_ROOT%bin\;%GSL_ROOT%bin\;%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins;%PATH%"
SET "GDAL_DATA=%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal-data"
SET "GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins"
SET "PYTHONPATH=%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\python\osgeo;%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\python;%SDK_ROOT%bin\ms\python;%SDK_ROOT%bin\proj6\apps;%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\apps;%SDK_ROOT%bin\curl;%SDK_ROOT%bin;%SDK_ROOT%bin\ms\apps;%SDK_ROOT%bin\proj6\share"
SET "PROJ_LIB=%SDK_ROOT%bin\proj6\share;%SDK_ROOT%bin\proj6\apps"
SET "LD_LIB_PATH=%SDK_ROOT%gsl2\lib"



gdal_translate -gcp 0.0000 0.0000 80.207539 16.173769 -gcp 2683 0.0000 80.263502 16.173386 -gcp 0.0000 7906 80.206398 16.028650 -gcp 2683 7906 80.262312 16.028034 -gcp 1341 3953 80.234943 16.101114 HH_Amp.bin HH_Amp_geo.bin

pause
```

I specified the gdal_translate at the end of the script.

Now, I have specified the gdal_driver path in the script. To be sure, I also specified it in the path variable. But, where is this error coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a path problem, but you'd have to specify output format to the commands while giving input as any other image than tiff format.

```
gdal_translate -of ENVI -gcp 0.0000 0.0000 80.207539 16.173769 -gcp 2683 0.0000 80.263502 16.173386 -gcp 0.0000 7906 80.206398 16.028650 -gcp 2683 7906 80.262312 16.028034 -gcp 1341 3953 80.234943 16.101114 HH_Amp.bin HH_Amp_geo.bin
```

Solved the problem by adding the flag `-of ENVI` to the command.